# Nesting hover:not in SASS is not working

Tags: sass

How can i put the following css into SASS/SCSS? :

```
.lowernav>li>a:hover:not(.active) 
{
  background-color: #FF4E4E;
  color: white; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the :not selector before the hover selector:

```
.lowernav {
     > li {
         > a {
             // base styling

              &:not(.active):hover { // Hover styling
                  background-color: #FF4E4E;
                  color: white; 
              }
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: The ampersand will be .lowernav > li > a, you could also use .lowernav > li > a:not(.active):hover, if you don't have base styling on the anchor tag